# Using proguard to obfuscate applications

Tags: java, android, obfuscation, proguard

I want to protect my app from decompiling. I read that I can achieve this trough ProGuard. So I deleted the `#` in the properties where it says, that this will enabled proguard, run my application and then decompiled it. And I can still see my original source code :/

Is there anything else to do?

Comment: If you are working with Eclipse, have you exported your application? Proguard only works when you do File|Export in Eclipse

Comment: okay that helped a lot (: but I can still read the pathes to some update servers etc., is it possible to do something that they aren't shown in plain text?

Comment: Proguard doesn't encrypt your strings. 3rd parties obfuscators do that but some informations (such as your server url) could be obtained just  sniffing your app network activity so I don't know if it worth to hide them.

Comment: String encryption is usually pretty easy to reverse or bypass pass anyway. Obfuscation will only slow people down a bit. It will never stop a dedicated reverse engineer.